# Make nested API call to fetch all list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

In my scenario, I've got an API call to hit and on the response of the API, I've to call the final API to get records of list.

From the first API, I'll get a flag on which I've to make the conditional API call to get the records.

The problem is, GET_LIST gets called by react-admin and in that, I cannot handle two asynchronous API call.

I tried with Query and custom DataSource.

This is the API type called by the react-admin to fetch list.

```
GET_LIST: {
      request(params: GetListParams): Ticket {
        return {
          method: 'GET',
          url: `${base}/q`,
          headers: makeHeaders(token),
          query: mapQueryParams(params, universalFilters)
        }
      },

      response(res: Object): {total: number, data: Array<Contact>} {
        const {hits, rows} = res
        return {
          total: hits,
          data: rows.map(row => {
            return {...row, id: getId(row)}
          })
        }
      }
    },
```

This is the component that is called for the list.

```
export const ContactList = (props) => {
  return (
    <List {...props} filters={<Search />} bulkActionButtons={<PostBulkActions />}>
      <Datagrid className="data-grid">
        <GravatarField source="email" label="" sortable={false} />

        <LinkField
          source="first"
          label="First Name"
          text={ ({first}) => first }
          deriveUrl={ ({id}) => `/#/contacts/${id}` }
          target='' />

        <LinkField  
          source="last"
          label="Last Name"
          text={ ({last}) => last || '(unknown name)' }
          deriveUrl={ ({id}) => `/#/contacts/${id}` }
          target='' />

        <DateField source="lastActivity" />
        <TextField source="email" />
        <PhoneNumberField source="primaryPhone" label="Phone" sortable={false} />
        <MultiTagField source="tags" sortable={false} deletable={false} />
        {/* <DeleteButton /> */}
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your code, this should be the job of your dataprovider. As it should return a promise, you can make the two api calls in it and resolve only after you get the second call response